# Openpyxl запись string

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Необходимо записывать в excel файл информацию каждый раз в новую ячейку, в первом столбике. Открыл файл и нужный лист:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='log.xlsx')
ws = wb['log']
```

Список содержащий int, записывается без проблем:

```
ws.append([1, 2, 3])
```

При попытке записать список содержащий str, файл увеличивает объем, но все ячейки пусты:

```
ws.append(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Comment: @MaxU файл сохраняется и закрывается, вопрос в другом, цифры в файл записываются, а строки нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендовал бы сделать следующее:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('testfile.xlsx')
ws= wb['Log']
col = 'A' #буква столбца, куда будет писаться информация
for i in range(100): # range устанавливайте уже, в зависимости, от задачи
   ws[col + str(i)] = '123' # теперь каждый раз в столбец A[i] будет записываться некая информация. A1,A2,A3...An
wb.save('testfile.xlsx')
```

Comment: В том то и проблема, что range с каждым разом изменяется, необходимо записывать новую информацию в столбец А, но в пустую ячейку снизу, а согласно Вашему коду, информация будет перезаписываться во всех ячейках

Comment: Например, вы можете запоминать предыдущий range и следующий уже начинать с предыдущего +1. Все зависит от типа вашей задачи